# Can't access property inside object initializer

Tags: c#

Consider the following code.

```
List<MyFiles> files = new List<MyFiles>();
....
while (reader.Read())
{
    var a = new MyFiles
    {
       FileName = reader["Filename"].ToString(),
       FileLocation = reader["Filelocation"].ToString(),
       FullPath = FileLocation + @"\" + FileName // Error at this line
    };
   files.Add(a);
}
```

The above is a snippet from my method which uses `SqlDataReader` to fetch data from the database. Everything works fine expect when I try to assign value to `FullPath` property I get the following error message:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MyFiles.FileLocation'
>   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MyFiles.FileName'

I know I can make those properties static or create an instance and access them via e.g. `var b = new MyFiles(); b.FileLocation ..`

But my question is why can't I use `FileLocation` and `FileName` as I am in the above code snippet. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You can use another local variable.

Comment: the _why_ will be to do with the values of those properties not being available yet, probably to do with them not being assigned to a location on the heap, I'd imagine - though that's a total guess.

Comment: @Code what is your .Net Framework version ? That feature is not enable under C# 3

Comment: @SurenSrapyan It's 4.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access the property of an instance which you are just initializing.

You can use local variables:

```
int fileNameColumnOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("Filename");
int fileLocationColumnOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("Filelocation");
while (reader.Read())
{
    string fileName = reader.GetString(fileNameColumnOrdinal);
    string fileLocation = reader.GetString(fileLocationColumnOrdinal);
    var a = new MyFiles
    {
       FileName = fileName,
       FileLocation = fileLocation,
       FullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(fileLocation, fileName)
    };
   files.Add(a);
}
```

I also recommend to use  `System.IO.Path.Combine`.

Comment: I can access `FileName` and `Location` as `FileName = reader["Filename"].ToString(), ..` it's when I try to use them for `FullPath` I get the error. Is there in particular reason they can't be used that way

Comment: @Code: you can set  those properties since that's the object initializer, but you cannot read them. The object is yet not fully initialized, that's why the compiler doesn't allow it.

Comment: @Code: it's even possible that you have a local variable `FileName` which you use to initialize the `FileName` property in the object initializer(to test it rename `fileName` to `FileName`). The compiler won't complain because the getter of the object-property `FileName` is not accessible in this context.

Comment: I just tried that and you're right the compiler doesn't complain :/

Comment: @Code: don't do it because it's confusing (but working) to have: `var a = new MyFiles
    {
       FileName = FileName
    };`. Local variables should start  lower-case anyway.

Comment: Just a quick one, I thought `GetString()` only accept `int` as param and not `string`

Answer (score 2):

When creating a new object and set some properties using this syntax: `var foo = new bar { a = 123 };` You can only set properties, not using them. You have to use some helper variables or setting the properties via: `foo.a = 456;`.

**Solution 1**

```
List<MyFiles> files = new List<MyFiles>();
....
while (reader.Read())
{
    string fileName = reader["Filename"].ToString();
    string fileLocation = reader["Filelocation"].ToString();

    var a = new MyFiles
    {
       FileName = fileName,
       FileLocation = fileLocation,
       FullPath = fileLocation + @"\" + fileName // Error at this line
    };
   files.Add(a);
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
List<MyFiles> files = new List<MyFiles>();
....
while (reader.Read())
{
    var a = new MyFiles()

    a.FileName = reader["Filename"].ToString();
    a.FileLocation = reader["Filelocation"].ToString();
    a.FullPath = a.FileName + @"\" + a.FileLocation // Error at this line
   files.Add(a);
}
```

**Solution 3**

You can create a custom getter for `FullPath`:

```
public string FullPath
{
    get { return FileName + @"\" + FileLocation; }
}
```

**EDIT**

I think there is no specific reason for this. It's by design, so some c# developer thought, we don't need this :) I think it would be possible, but just not implemented. It should be possible, because the created IL-Code is the same as in my solution 2 and it is only some syntactical sugar.

Comment: I know this to be the case but any idea why it is the case? What's going on under the hood? I presume something like the object "a" hasn't made it onto the heap yet? It's in some transient state?

Comment: Ok, added my point of view. It's not really an answer, but as much as i know.

Comment: You can't do that because it's explicitly prohibited by the [C#
Language Specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029): *It is not possible for
the object initializer to refer to the newly created object it is initializing.* (cfr. §7.6.10.2 Object initializers). Why they decided to explicitly forbid it? It's not explained, you should ask Jon Skeet. :D

Comment: @Albireo Thank you for the link. Would definitely ask Jon Skeet to shed some light on this if possible